# Magento 2.4 Sidebar\RemoveItem - afterExecute() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http

Tags: magento2.4, plugin

I get this error:

> TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> ..\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Sidebar\RemoveItemPlugin::afterExecute()
> must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http, instance
> of Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json\Interceptor given

It was working fine on Magento 2.3 but after the upgrade to 2.4, I get the above error. My code:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Vendor\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Sidebar;

class RemoveItemPlugin
{
    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $result
    ): \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http {
        /* Do something */
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In scope of implementation [Decomposition of Magento Controllers](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Decomposition-of-Magento-Controllers/ba-p/430883) this controller [refactored](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/27463/files) to returning instance of `\Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json` (which implements `\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface`).

Previously this controller used `\Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http` as return type of `execute` method.

Anyway, both types are correct according phpdoc of `\Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface::execute` method.

```
/**
 * Execute action based on request and return result
 *
 * @return \Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface|ResponseInterface
 * @throws \Magento\Framework\Exception\NotFoundException
 */
public function execute();
```

To fix this issue for 2.4 version, you should change type of `$result` argument to
`\Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultInterface`. To have a fix, which will be compatible with two versions of magento (2.3 and 2.4), just skip defining type from method signature and check type of result using `instance of` inside of you plugin, if this is required for your case.

Comment: I also had this issue but wasn't able to return the cart like it did in the previous class. The issue is $content = $this->json->unserialize($result->getContent()); where getContent no longer exists in $result as its now ResultInterface. Do you know how to render the cart JSON from ResultInterface?

Comment: I also had this issue but wasn't able to return the cart like it did in the previous class. The issue is $content = $this->json->unserialize($result->getContent()); where getContent no longer exists in $result as its now ResultInterface. Do you know how to render the cart JSON from ResultInterface?