# afterExecute() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http in plugin Magento 2.4 upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, plugin

I have a plugin in my module that was working in Magento 2.3, but after upgrade to 2.4 i am getting the error

> TypeError: Argument 2 passed to
> ..\Plugin\Controller\Checkout\Sidebar\RemoveItemPlugin::afterExecute()
> must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http, instance
> of Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Json\Interceptor given

This is the code :

```
use Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPoolInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json;

class RemoveItemPlugin
{
    public function __construct(
        SectionPoolInterface $sectionPool,
        Json $json
    ) {
        $this->sectionPool = $sectionPool;
        $this->json = $json;
    }

    public function afterExecute(
        \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem $subject,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http $result
    ): \Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http {

        /* Get Cart Items */
        $sectionNames = "cart";
        $sectionNames = $sectionNames ? array_unique(\explode(',', $sectionNames)) : null;
        $forceNewSectionTimestamp = false;
        $response = $this->sectionPool->getSectionsData($sectionNames, (bool)$forceNewSectionTimestamp);


        /* Prepare Result */
        $content = $this->json->unserialize($result->getContent());
        $content['cartSection'] = $response;
        $content = $this->json->serialize($content);

        $result->setContent($content);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

I tried the answer in this question :

[Magento 2.4 Sidebar\RemoveItem - afterExecute() must be an instance of Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/351344/magento-2-4-sidebar-removeitem-afterexecute-must-be-an-instance-of-magento-f)

but once I change $result to be type resultInterface, I can no longer use $result->getContent() to return the cart json. Is there a way to do this with resultInterface?

I have tried this also but i get the error invalid return type

```
    /* Prepare Result */
    $content = (array)$result;
    $content['cartSection'] = $response;
    $content2 = $this->json->serialize($content);

    return $content2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do -

```
public function afterExecute(
    \Magento\Checkout\Controller\Sidebar\RemoveItem $subject,
    $result
) { 
   // your code
   $result->setData(['key' => 'value']);
   return $result;
}
```

Whatever you are trying to return just pass as `[]` with `key,value` pair

Because - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/4c36116dcf878e127059d9be9566a119783583f2/app/code/Magento/Checkout/Controller/Sidebar/RemoveItem.php#L111
and
https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/4c36116dcf878e127059d9be9566a119783583f2/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/Controller/Result/Json.php#L59 will take care of data